# Apply coupon with Ajax in Magento 2

Tags: magento2.4.3.p1

I have to apply coupon with loading the page and display error or success message below the coupon input box.

I have override the coupon post controller in the custom module and applied ajax.

Ajax is working but page is reloading showing json message on the page example.com/checkout/cart/couponPost/

```
$('#discount-coupon-form .action.apply').on('click', function (e) {
    if ($('#discount-coupon-form').valid()) {
                var url = $('#discount-coupon-form').attr('action');
                e.preventDefault();
                $.ajax({
                    url: url,
                    data: $('#discount-coupon-form').serialize(),
                    method: 'post',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    showLoader:true,
                    success: function (data) {
                        if (data.errorMsg) {
                            console.log(data.errorMsg);
                        } else {
                            console.log(data.successMsg);
                        }
                    }
                });
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        });

class CouponPost extends \Magento\Checkout\Controller\Cart\CouponPost
{
     $result = $this->resultJsonFactory->create();
     $result->setData($response);
     return $result;
}[![enter image description here][1]][1]
```

Comment: Which controller path you have set in form action ??

Comment: http://test.localhost.com/checkout/cart/couponPost/

Comment: I have overridden this couponPost controller in custom module

Comment: Check In your ajax request your controller is call or not ... Might be it's calling the default magento controller..

Comment: My controller is calling. Json response is also showing after page reload